# Update column A base on the left join latest column datetime record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Need to update the column base on the left join latest record. Like for example below

TABLE A:

| ID | NAME | CREATED | UPDATED | DELIVERY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P#A | 2021-01-05 00:23:00 |  |  |

TABLE B:

| ID | TABLE_A_ID | DESCRIPTION | CREATED | ESTIMATED DELIVERY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Processing | 2021-01-05 12:00:00 |  |
| 2 | 1 | Packing | 2021-01-06 12:00:00 | 2021-01-07 00:23:00 |
| 3 | 1 | Shipped | 2021-01-06 12:00:00 | 2021-01-08 00:23:00 |
| 3 | 1 | Delivere | 2021-01-06 12:00:00 |  |

Base on above tables how can I migrate estimated delivery from table b to table a's estimated delivery column?

Below code giving me error. `You can't specify target table 'TableA' for update in FROM clause`

```php
TableA::leftJoin('table_b as b', function ($join) {
  $join->on('tableA.id', '=', 'b.table_a_id');
  $join->whereRaw('b.table_a_id = (SELECT a.id FROM table_a as a LEFT JOIN table_b as b on a.id = b.table_a_id WHERE b.estimated_delivery IS NOT NULL GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY b.estimated_delivery DESC LIMIT 1)');
})->update(['table_a.delivery' => DB::raw('b.estimated_delivery')])
```

Any suggestions for this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a violation of SSOT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth). Isn't better to change your queries to get the `delivery` info from table B?

Comment: A LEFT JOIN in an UPDATE is a slightly strange thing.